# How this kind of photography is achieved?

Tags: photoshop, digital

https://www.flickr.com/photos/44117072@N07/14001910788/in/photostream/lightbox/
[image]

Is this just some great skill of photoshop?
As you can see, happening in the first building. The fish aquarium is totally made up and the roof looks drawn.

Ans also, is there a name for this kind of photography? 
Fusion of real world ith cartoon like.

EDIT: Photos added below to show actual location

[image]

[image]

Comment: how is what achieved? looks like architecture photography in mist to me

Comment: Please read [Important information for asking “What's this effect?” questions](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3881/important-information-for-asking-whats-this-effect-questions) and edit your question to include the sort of information listed there. Thanks!

Comment: @flolilolilo the effect on the first building.

Comment: what effect? the glow from the light? the straight lines?

Comment: @flolilolilo you don't find the picture a bit peculiar? Just Please explain what has happened here.

Comment: What is "peculiar" to you may be old hat to someone else. Please describe the effect you are interested in.

Comment: The aquarium is just stickers on the windows. Maybe a sporting equipment store.

Comment: @user16259 my initial thought too. Isn't it just stickers?

Comment: The aquarium is just stickers on the window of the "Ixtapa" Tex Mex seafood restaurant at 10221 Garland Rd, Dallas, Texas.  I found it by doing a google search for "Keller's Hamburgers" which appears in the background of the photo.

Comment: I think this is a nice photograph, and that its not fair to accuse a photographer of making up images using so called 'artificial editing'.

Comment: You can only enhance images using editing, not completely make them up...

Comment: @JanardanS I never said he made it up. I just find it so surreal  how the photo appears to be and hat's off to him.

Comment: @JanardanS oh yes, you can. Ever heard about CGI or hyperrealism?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it looks peculiar. This could easily have been achieved in camera - they found a building with some unusual windows, then they went there at night in the mist to take the photo. If you read the comments on the photo, they specified that they took it on Kodak Ektar 100 film at f5.6. Kodak Ektar is a very fine grain film. The photographer stated in their comments that they couldn't remember the exposure time, but based on the fact that it's at night, and on ISO 100 film and at f5.6, I'd hazard a guess at somewere around 5-10 seconds (noting that this is speculation because I think we can't really tell how bright the ambient light is).

Comment: Where can I find more of these?

Comment: And yes I read the comments, but I am a total noob in photography I don't know what difference a film can make!

Comment: @Shad find more of what? It's a photo of a building at night with some mist. The slow film speed of 100 ISO means that the film isn't super sensitive to light compared to other films of higher ISO. This usually results in less grain, but also, it means that you need longer exposure time to get a correct exposure (if you want to know more about this, research the 'exposure triangle', there are some great explanations on this site)